# PHPIDS on php 8.1 Deprecated Errors

Tags: php

i got a problem with PHPIDS on a PHP 8.1 Server.

Here the Errors:

```
PHP Deprecated: Return type of IDS\Report::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phpids\ib\IDS\Report.php on line 205

PHP Deprecated: Return type of IDS\Report::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phpids\lib\IDS\Report.php on line 218
```

I know Deprecated Errors are not that bad, but i want that everything works Perfect.
I Searched in Google several things but no  solution found.
Hopefully you find the problem.

i use the actual PHPIDS version from Github (https://github.com/PHPIDS/PHPIDS)
i know this version is not the newest but i didn't found a newer one.

thx for the help

and here the Script Report.php

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPIDS
 *
 * Requirements: PHP5, SimpleXML
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008 PHPIDS group (https://phpids.org)
 *
 * PHPIDS is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * PHPIDS is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with PHPIDS. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 * PHP version 5.1.6+
 *
 * @category Security
 * @package  PHPIDS
 * @author   Mario Heiderich <mario.heiderich@gmail.com>
 * @author   Christian Matthies <ch0012@gmail.com>
 * @author   Lars Strojny <lars@strojny.net>
 * @license  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html LGPL
 * @link     http://php-ids.org/
 */
namespace IDS;

/**
 * PHPIDS report object
 *
 * The report objects collects a number of events and thereby presents the
 * detected results. It provides a convenient API to work with the results.
 *
 * Note that this class implements Countable, IteratorAggregate and
 * a __toString() method
 *
 * @category  Security
 * @package   PHPIDS
 * @author    Christian Matthies <ch0012@gmail.com>
 * @author    Mario Heiderich <mario.heiderich@gmail.com>
 * @author    Lars Strojny <lars@strojny.net>
 * @copyright 2007-2009 The PHPIDS Group
 * @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html LGPL
 * @link      http://php-ids.org/
 */
class Report implements \Countable, \IteratorAggregate
{
    /**
     * Event container
     *
     * @var Event[]|array
     */
    protected $events = array();

    /**
     * List of affected tags
     *
     * This list of tags is collected from the collected event objects on
     * demand when IDS_Report->getTags() is called
     *
     * @var string[]|array
     */
    protected $tags = array();

    /**
     * Impact level
     *
     * The impact level is calculated on demand by adding the results of the
     * event objects on IDS\Report->getImpact()
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $impact = 0;

    /**
     * Centrifuge data
     *
     * This variable - initiated as an empty array - carries all information
     * about the centrifuge data if available
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $centrifuge = array();

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param array $events the events the report should include
     *
     * @return Report
     */
    public function __construct(array $events = null)
    {
        foreach ((array) $events as $event) {
            $this->addEvent($event);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds an IDS_Event object to the report
     *
     * @param Event $event IDS_Event
     *
     * @return self $this
     */
    public function addEvent(Event $event)
    {
        $this->clear();
        $this->events[$event->getName()] = $event;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get event by name
     *
     * In most cases an event is identified by the key of the variable that
     * contained maliciously appearing content
     *
     * @param string|integer $name the event name
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if argument is invalid
     * @return Event|null                    IDS_Event object or false if the event does not exist
     */
    public function getEvent($name)
    {
        if (!is_scalar($name)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid argument type given');
        }

        return $this->hasEvent($name) ? $this->events[$name] : null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns list of affected tags
     *
     * @return string[]|array
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        if (!$this->tags) {
            $this->tags = array();

            foreach ($this->events as $event) {
                $this->tags = array_merge($this->tags, $event->getTags());
            }

            $this->tags = array_values(array_unique($this->tags));
        }

        return $this->tags;
    }

    /**
     * Returns total impact
     *
     * Each stored IDS_Event object and its IDS_Filter sub-object are called
     * to calculate the overall impact level of this request
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getImpact()
    {
        if (!$this->impact) {
            $this->impact = 0;
            foreach ($this->events as $event) {
                $this->impact += $event->getImpact();
            }
        }

        return $this->impact;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a specific event with given name exists
     *
     * @param string|integer $name the event name
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if argument is illegal
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasEvent($name)
    {
        if (!is_scalar($name)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid argument given');
        }

        return isset($this->events[$name]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns total amount of events
     *
     * @return integer
     */


    
    public function count()
    {
        return @count($this->events);
    }
    /**
     * Return iterator object
     *
     * In order to provide the possibility to directly iterate over the
     * IDS_Event object the IteratorAggregate is implemented. One can easily
     * use foreach() to iterate through all stored IDS_Event objects.
     *
     * @return \Iterator the event collection
     */
    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new \ArrayIterator($this->events);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if any events are registered
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isEmpty()
    {
        return empty($this->events);
    }

    /**
     * Clears calculated/collected values
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function clear()
    {
        $this->impact = 0;
        $this->tags   = array();
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the centrifuge property or null if not
     * filled with data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCentrifuge()
    {
        return $this->centrifuge;
    }

    /**
     * This method sets the centrifuge property
     *
     * @param array $centrifuge the centrifuge data
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if argument is illegal
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCentrifuge(array $centrifuge = array())
    {
        if (!$centrifuge) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Empty centrifuge given');
        }
        $this->centrifuge = $centrifuge;
    }

    /**
     * Directly outputs all available information
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        $output = '';
        if (!$this->isEmpty()) {
            $output .= vsprintf(
                "Total impact: %d<br/>\nAffected tags: %s<br/>\n",
                array(
                    $this->getImpact(),
                    implode(', ', $this->getTags())
                )
            );

            foreach ($this->events as $event) {
                $output .= vsprintf(
                    "<br/>\nVariable: %s | Value: %s<br/>\nImpact: %d | Tags: %s<br/>\n",
                    array(
                        htmlspecialchars($event->getName()),
                        htmlspecialchars($event->getValue()),
                        $event->getImpact(),
                        implode(', ', $event->getTags())
                    )
                );

                foreach ($event as $filter) {
                    $output .= vsprintf(
                        "Description: %s | Tags: %s | ID %s<br/>\n",
                        array(
                            $filter->getDescription(),
                            implode(', ', $filter->getTags()),
                            $filter->getId()
                        )
                    );
                }
            }

            $output .= '<br/>';

            if ($centrifuge = $this->getCentrifuge()) {
                $output .= vsprintf(
                    "Centrifuge detection data<br/> Threshold: %s<br/> Ratio: %s",
                    array(
                        isset($centrifuge['threshold']) && $centrifuge['threshold'] ? $centrifuge['threshold'] : '---',
                        isset($centrifuge['ratio']) && $centrifuge['ratio'] ? $centrifuge['ratio'] : '---'
                    )
                );
                if (isset($centrifuge['converted'])) {
                    $output .= '<br/>  Converted: ' . $centrifuge['converted'];
                }
                $output .= "<br/><br/>\n";
            }
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of PHP 8.1, you have to fix the return type of the functions `count()` and `getIterator()` to match with interfaces.

- `public count(): int` (see [Countable](https://www.php.net/Countable))
- `public getIterator(): Traversable` (see [IteratorAggregate](https://www.php.net/IteratorAggregate))

```php
class Report implements \Countable, \IteratorAggregate
{
    protected array $events;

    public function count(): int
    {
        return count($this->events);
    }

    public function getIterator(): \Traversable
    {
        return new \ArrayIterator($this->events);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error now: `Could not check compatibility between IDS\Report::getIterator(): IDS\Traversable and IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, because class IDS\Traversable is not available in phpids\lib\IDS\Report.php on line 218`

Comment: Updated. Add backslash `\Traversable` to return type of `getIterator`. because the current namespace is IDS.