# PHP - symfony/console library thorws deprecated error with 8.1

Tags: php

When running my **PHP** project which is now using version `8.1.` I get the error:

> PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project-core/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 111

Tried:

```
php composer.phar update vendor/symfony/console
```

and got the same error.

Also tried:

```
composer update symfony/console
```

and I got conflicts like:

> Problem 1
> - facebook/webdriver is locked to version 1.2.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
> - facebook/webdriver 1.2.0 requires php ^5.5 || ~7.0 -> your php version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 2
> - cakephp/collection 3.10.1 requires php >=5.6.0,<8.0.0 -> your php version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - robmorgan/phinx 0.10.8 requires cakephp/collection ^3.6 -> satisfiable by cakephp/collection[3.10.1].
> - robmorgan/phinx is locked to version 0.10.8 and an update of this package was not requested.

I also checked [THIS LINK](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/42199). Can someone help me figure out this problem?

I have also seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71099351/phpids-on-php-8-1-deprecated-errors) but I do not think it solves the issue as I can not edit vendor files..

Comment: Looks like you need to update your dependencies since they are for a lower PHP version than you're using. facebook/webdriver requires php ^5.5 || ~7.0 and cakephp/collection requires php >=5.6.0,<8.0.0. You need to find out what versions of those libraries you need to update to.

Comment: Does that mean I need to change the versions in my json file and then run composer update? @M.Eriksson

Comment: Ensure that all your dependencies supports PHP8.1

Comment: `facebook/webdriver` is even abandoned use `php-webdriver/webdriver` as suggeted: https://packagist.org/packages/facebook/webdriver

Comment: If you have those in your composer.json file, then you can remove them, do a composer update and then add them using `composer require facebook/driver` and `composer require cakephp/collection` and it should install the versions that matches your system. However, if you don't have them in your composer file, then you need to find out what libraries has them as dependencies and update those libraries. And make sure they aren't abandoned, as Justinas pointed out.

Comment: - Root composer.json requires symfony/console ^6.0, found symfony/console[v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.8] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
@M.Eriksson

Comment: I have mede it to codeception/codeception which has support untip PHP 8.0. and I have 8.1. What should I do? @Justinas

Comment: codeception/codeception:^4.1 should be fine

Comment: Yap, that is the one I have in json file. But still an error:   - codeception/codeception[4.1.0, ..., 4.1.8] require php >=5.6.0 <8.0 -> your php version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - codeception/codeception[4.1.9, ..., 4.1.31] require symfony/console >=2.7 <6.0 -> found symfony/console[v2.7.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.41, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.0.0).
    - Root composer.json requires codeception/codeception ^4.1 -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[4.1.0, ..., 4.1.31]. @Justinas

Answer (score 0):

It could be that composer itself needs to be updated, rather than the dependencies you are trying to install.

Upgrading composer v2.0.9 to v2.5.0 was the fix I needed to silence deprecation notices mentioning symfony.

Depending on how you installed composer, and whether you've renamed the phar to just composer and put it in your path, that is done with:

> php composer.phar self-update

or

> composer self-update

Add sudo if permissions require.